# Does calling stopUpdatingLocation on CLLocationManager also stop monitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Tags: ios, ios7, cllocationmanager

I want to verify what happens if I call startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges on an instance of CLLocationManager and then call stopUpdatingLocation. The documentation says to call this method when my app no longer needs to receive location-related events, but there is also a separate method stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges. So I'm not sure if calling stopUpdatingLocation would also stop these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are related but independent.  They are started and stopped separately.

One common scenario is to call `stopUpdatingLocation` and `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` in `applicationWillResignActive` in order to increase battery life.

When your app returns to the foreground the significant location change is stopped and location monitoring is started again

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification and the extra information.

Comment: I tested this by calling startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges and then calling stopUpdatingLocation after I got the didUpdateLocation call back. Putting the simulator into freeway drive mode, I kept on getting periodic location updates even though I had called the stopUpdatingLocation method.