# Core Location: best practices for switching between Significant Location service and the Standard Location service?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, cllocationmanager

Sometimes my app needs to use the higher precision, more frequent standard location updates and sometimes all it needs are the significant location updates. The most common time that I need to make this switch is when the app switches between foreground and background.

When switching between these services:

- Do I need to switch one off and the other on, as if they are separate services that don't affect each other?

  - Standard->Significant:
    `[myLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [myLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];`
  - Significant->Standard:
    `[myLocationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];`
- Do these services turn each other off when they themselves are turned on, such that I never need to stop them, only start them?

  - Standard->Significant:
    `[myLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];`
  - Significant->Standard:
    `[myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];`
- Do I just start the significant service when I set up my app and leave it on, only starting and stopping the standard service (extra accuracy) when needed?

  - Initial setup:
    `[myLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];`
  - Standard->Significant:
    `[myLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];`
  - Significant->Standard:
    `[myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];`

The documentation for CLLocationManager is unclear on the details of this behavior. Thank you for any helpful thoughts!

*Edit: Just discovered some helpful information on another question, ruling out the second possible behavior mentioned above, but not suggesting the best way to manage this switch: [Does calling stopUpdatingLocation on CLLocationManager also stop monitoringSignificantLocationChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934503/does-calling-stopupdatinglocation-on-cllocationmanager-also-stop-monitoringsigni)*